# SQL Script to know where the data is located

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

My question might sound  stupid, but does there exist a script that could find out where in database, for which tables, is the desired data located? Say for example, i need to found where Texas is located in database, in which tables and in which column.

There exists a script that could find out the tables, SP, views based on the column name provided. Is there any script that could find out tables, column name etc based on the actual data?

Hope the question is understood.

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh Walker has a script that will find the number of incidences a string of text is found, and in which tables:

[http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/65769/](http://sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/65769/)

And, this statement should find any procedure code that contains the text you are looking for:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM syscomments
WHERE [text] LIKE '%whatever%'
```

Comment: Depending on your collation, it may sometimes be necessary to: lower([text]) LIKE '%whatever%'

Comment: Thanks Seth/NTDLS for the response but the script doesn't really works.

Answer (score 1):

The [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) gives you this kind of search functionality plus various other cool things for free. And no, I don't work for them!

Comment: SSMS tools pack just rocks!!!! Aware about any such other free tool which could provide some rocking out-of-the-imagination functionality

Answer (score 0):

I have got one great tool that can find data anywhere located in the database. It is known as SQL Locator. Just Google it, that should be easy to find. Plus it  is a freeware to download.

Thanks!